# How do i MD5 crypt password at registration?

Tags: php, mysqli

I downloaded a full php forum  and have been removing the errors and fixing things i didnt like with it.

Theres still one thing, I am not sure how to have my passwords stored as a MD5 key. whould be great if someone could rewrite this php code to crypt passwords of people who register.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../_database/database.php';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['signup_button'])){
        $user_email=$_REQUEST['user_email'];
        $user_firstname=$_REQUEST['user_firstname'];
        $user_lastname=$_REQUEST['user_lastname'];
        $user_username=$_REQUEST['user_username'];
        $user_password=$_REQUEST['user_password'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO user(user_firstname,user_lastname,user_email,user_username,user_password,user_joindate,user_avatar,user_backgroundpicture) VALUES('$user_firstname','$user_lastname','$user_email','$user_username','$user_password',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'default.jpg','default.jpg')";
        mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
        $_SESSION['user_username'] = $user_username;
        header('Location: ../update-profile-after-registration.php?user_username='.$user_username);
    }
?>
```

The register page calls for this code.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? If you are using PHP >= 5.5.0 I would suggest using `password_hash();` If you are not high enough but working with PHP5 as you said, you could try using ircmaxwell workaround [password_hash()](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You can use as `$user_password=md5($_REQUEST['user_password']);`

Comment: md5($user_password), but try to find another way of crypting your password. MD5 is not safe for storing passwords in database! Btw. This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213237/encrypt-password-in-md5

Comment: MD5 is not considered a secure method to hash passwords, please use the native PHP password library http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php You should also use paramterized/prepared queries to avoid sql injection hacks http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Where did you download this code? It's insecure as hell.

Comment: im not realy good with php and no clue how to figure out what version i am using. however, i belive im using php5

Comment: $user_password=md5($_REQUEST['user_password']); worked :) thanks alot!

Comment: why in God's name *(or whatever higher power you believe in),* would you want to use a hashing function that's over 30 years old and is totally unsafe to use in this century??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use like that for your `INSERT` Statement:

```
$user_password= md5($_REQUEST['user_password']);
```

**Now how can you select md5() password from database after insertion?**

Its very simple, you must need to follow same step:

```
$user_password= md5($_REQUEST['user_password']); // your input with md5
```

**[MD5() PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)**

As per manual, it will return you  the hash as a **32-character hexadecimal number**.

Here is the basic example of `md5()` hash convert and selection.

```
// convert md5 hash
$insertString = 'apple';
$convert_md5 = md5($insertString); // 1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f

// select md5 hash
$selectString = 'apple';
if (md5($selectString) === $convert_md5) {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
```

Comment: atleast add comments after downvote.... downvoters... how can i improve this if u didnt guide.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you probably got those because someone didn't agree in you're not instructing the OP in regards to the use of MD5 and including mentions/links of a password hashing function of *"this century"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: yes may be... just try to explain how it works... well my bad, but useful answer for OP .... :)

Comment: I agree. Oh well, what can you do ;-) People can be *strange animals* at times.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$user_password=MD5($_REQUEST['user_password']);` however, I **WOULD NOT** suggest doing this. `MD5` is not secure for password hashing anymore. Take a look at the `password_hash` function or `crypt` function for a more secure hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include '../_database/database.php';
        if(isset($_REQUEST['signup_button'])){
            $user_email=$_REQUEST['user_email'];
            $user_firstname=$_REQUEST['user_firstname'];
            $user_lastname=$_REQUEST['user_lastname'];
            $user_username=$_REQUEST['user_username'];
            $user_password=$_REQUEST['user_password'];


             $user_password = md5( $user_password);




            $sql="INSERT INTO user(user_firstname,user_lastname,user_email,user_username,user_password,user_joindate,user_avatar,user_backgroundpicture) VALUES('$user_firstname','$user_lastname','$user_email','$user_username','$user_password',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'default.jpg','default.jpg')";
            mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
            $_SESSION['user_username'] = $user_username;
            header('Location: ../update-profile-after-registration.php?user_username='.$user_username);
        }
    ?>
```